# How to create array of CSS3 Animation WebkitAnimationEnd Events

Tags: jquery, animation, css

Basically what I'm trying to do is set up one element to which I will apply about 5 different css3 animations. What I'm tryting to do is have the WebkitAnimationEnd Event trigger each of the five animations.

So as the 1st animation ends, it triggers the WebkitAnimationEnd event and activates the 2nd animation, and so on...

http://jsfiddle.net/lesballard/uFbUj/13/

Comment: that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/uFbUj/14/

Comment: hello, thank you for your response. But that doesn't quite work for me. I am going to create 3 different animations that will be applied to the same element. WHat I want to do is an event listener that will look for the end of 3 different animations. So I will apply the 1st animation, when WebkitAnimationEnd gets the end of the 1st animation, a class will be added that applies the 2nd animation and sets up event listenerner for the 2nd animation, when WebkitAnimationEnd triggers the end of the 3rd animation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have **event animation ends**.

you can see here when the animation ends [Demo](http://www.centerwow.com/main/portfolio/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
             document.getElementById('animation-03').addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function () {
                alert('CSS3 animation demo by centerwow/Yossi Levi')
            }, false);
         });
```

you can take idea from hera and matched to your request.

I hope that I help. thx